# Teradata - Group by date rage

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this scenario in which purchase orders for each items falling under a particular date range (each 7 days) has to be aggregated.

```
ITEM_NUMBER  ORDERED_DATE  ORDER_QUANTITY
1            06/01/2013    5
1            06/02/2013    12
1            06/03/2013    3
1            06/06/2013    8
1            06/18/2013    7
1            06/21/2013    9
1            06/29/2013    3
1            06/30/2013    4

2            06/03/2013    24
2            06/07/2013    1
2            06/19/2013    22
2            06/23/2013    12
2            06/30/2013    9
```

The above records has to be aggregated into 7 days window with respect to ITEM like below

```
Item 1 - Orders from 06/01/2013 to 06/07/2013 as one group (7 days)
Item 1 - Orders from 06/18/2013 to 06/24/2013 as second group (7 days)
Item 1 - Orders from 06/29/2013 to 07/05/2013 as third group (7 days)
Item 2 - Orders from 06/03/2013 to 07/09/2013 as forth group (7 days) and so on
```

Hence the final output should be

```
ITEM_NUMBER  MIN(ORDERED_DATE)  SUM(ORDER_QUANTITY)
1            06/01/2013         28
1            06/18/2013         16
1            06/29/2013         7

2            06/03/2013         25
2            06/19/2013         34
2            06/30/2013         9
```

Please apologize if this is a repetition.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
select  a.ITEM_NUMBER
      , b.O_DATE 
        + ((cast((a.ORDERED_DATE - b.O_DATE) as INT) / 7 MOD 7) * 7)
           as SEVEN_DAY_WINDOW
      , sum(ORDER_QUANTITY) as ORDER_QUANTITY
from your_table a
join (
   select ITEM_NUMBER, min(ORDERED_DATE) as O_DATE
   from   your_table
   group by ITEM_NUMBER
   ) b
on a.ITEM_NUMBER=b.ITEM_NUMBER
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But there is something still missing. The above query is not giving the correct result

Comment: to add some clarification to Nik's comment, it appears that the min dates (seven_day_window) from the result set are not what is expected in the question

Comment: @ChrisCamp I tested this on my system and the result was exactly as requested.  Do you have any idea in what way the results are incorrect?